# How to restrict payment methods by Attribute or Category?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3, magento2.4

I want to Restrict payment methods by attribute or category ? I am using Magento 2.4.0.

if someone have idea or solution please share with me, I am stuck in this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of places you could write a plugin to do this, luckily however if you take a look at `\Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList` the constructor has an `$additionalChecks` argument allowing you to pass in additional custom checks to restrict specific payment methods.
`etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <!-- Specify a custom check where `your_custom_restriction` is a unique value -->
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="additionalChecks" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="your_custom_restriction" xsi:type="string">your_custom_restriction</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <!-- Here we specify the class responsible for handling the check specified in the previous block -->
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mapping" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="your_custom_restriction" xsi:type="object">StackExchange\PaymentRestriction\Model\YourCustomRestriction</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

In `etc/catalog_attributes.xml` we also need to tell Magento to load our custom attribute value in the product object when we call `getProduct()` on the quote item.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="disable_some_method"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Our class `Model/YourCustomRestriction.php` will make the decision to include/exclude the payment method. Our `isApplicable()` method should return `true` or `false` if we want to allow or block the payment method. In my example below I first check if the payment is `braintree` (if not we immediately return `true`). If it is, we iterate over all items in the cart and if one of the items has the attribute `disable_some_method` set to yes we break from the loop, return `true`, which in turn returns `false` preventing the payment method from being used.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\PaymentRestriction\Model;

use Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use PayPal\Braintree\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider;

class YourCustomRestriction implements SpecificationInterface
{
    /**
     * @param MethodInterface $paymentMethod
     * @param Quote $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isApplicable(MethodInterface $paymentMethod, Quote $quote)
    {
        if ($paymentMethod->getCode() === ConfigProvider::CODE && $this->hasRestrictedItems($quote)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param Quote $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    private function hasRestrictedItems(Quote $quote)
    {
        $hasRestrictedItems = false;
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $item */
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getDisableSomeMethod()) {
                $hasRestrictedItems = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $hasRestrictedItems;
    }
}
```